# AngularJS watch - unable to set breakpoint in chrome using devtools workspaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Does the watch service create a proxy of the original function ?

```
$scope.$watch('query', doSearch, true);
```

where :

```
doSearch = function(query) {
  alert("breakpoint not working");
  // stuff
}
```

The alert gets shown, but if I add a breakpoint to the code using chrome debugger, its does not break at all. Whereas other break points in non-watched javascript functions work as normal.

**Update :**
The break point works fine when I don't use the [workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) feature of chrome dev tools.

Comment: In their source code, it looks like they do "wrap" the function passed (`var originalFn = watcher.fn;`...`originalFn.call(this, newVal, oldVal, scope);`), but that shouldn't affect breakpoints and debugging...

Comment: @Ian why shouldn't it ? I am also using chrome workspaces but don;t think this makes a difference.

Comment: I mean, it's still calling the exact function you passed to it. If it had somehow constructed a totally new function and discarded what you passed, that would be a different story (I'm not sure how or why they would do that). Hmm I'll try debugging it in a normal Chrome browser and let you know if I have this problem

Comment: Hmm a breakpoint inside the `doSearch` function seems to halt execution for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TH8Ke/ - is that code similar enough to yours (I obviously left out the `alert`)

Comment: @Ian ok thanks, I will try not using workspaces, maybe that is the problem then.

Comment: @Ian yeah this works fine if I don;t use the workspaces features of chrome dev tools, weird... who do I tell I wonder.

Comment: Haha I have no idea! I guess report a bug to Chrome. I'm glad we at least narrowed it down

Comment: Just an idea, but you may want to try Chrome Canary to see if this same behavior occurs there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `debugger`  command..
For me it works when regular breakpoints to work on chrome.